# JavaScript issue only one responsive mode (mobile)

Tags: javascript, responsive

I have an HTML page that has a dropdown. If I change the dropdown selected option, it displays the value in the console. This is working well in a desktop browser version. The issue is when I change the mode in my browser to mobile or use a real mobile. No matter what dropdown option I select, it always shows the value of the first one. Is there some conflict with the responsive libraries I'm using that I seem not able to figure out? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <title>Admin</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
        table{
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active">
                     <a href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="active">
                     <a href="#">Log Out<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container">
         <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
         <table id="submissions" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Preview</th>
                  <th>Text</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Download</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>
                     Ya, ya la fuente se secó, el canario ya<br>murió
                     Pero aquí, no hay novedad
                     No, no te<br>preocupes por mí
                     Aquí todo sigue igual, como<br>cuando estabas tú
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <select class="form-control" id="states_1" onchange="changeState(this.id);">
                        <option value="A" selected="selected">Approved</option>
                        <option value="P">Pending</option>
                        <option value="R">Rejected</option>
                     </select>
                     <br/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
      <!-- /container -->
      <script>
         $('#submissions').DataTable();
         function changeState(id) {
            console.log($('#'+id).val());
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: working on desktop browser]

[image: not working on mobile browser]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code show correct console.logs on my phone device and "switched to phone" browser. Maybe you are testing another code because youre attached mobile view is not like what im seeing.

edit:

replace youre function

```
function changeState(id) {
        console.log($('#'+id).val());
     }
```

with this:

```
$("body").on("change", "#states_1", function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
     })
```

and remove inline "onchange="changeState(this.id);" on select tag, to became like this:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="states_1">
                    <option value="A"selected="selected">Approved</option>
                    <option value="P">Pending</option>
                    <option value="R">Rejected</option>
                 </select>
```

Comment: I don't know why you said that but I went and uploaded the code to JSBin and it is behaving the same (same bug) try it please and try to resize the screen to move form responsive to desktop and test: https://jsbin.com/haqunov/edit?html,console,output

Comment: oh i got you now, check the edited answer

Comment: hmmm ok it is working well now, but this does not answer why it behaves that way only in mobile. As far as I know, having onchange="" in the inline way should work fine. Thanks.

Comment: Because on mobile you have that tiny little blue + button that make jquery change in DOM and youre select tag lose its onchange event after pressing that button